# Add a where clause in SQL Server CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have used a SQL Server CTE for selecting data from my self-referencing table whose schema is

```
CREATE TABLE BaseDomainTable
(  
     [BaseModelId] INT,
     [Comments] NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
     [ParentModelId] INT NULL 
)
```

Each `ModelId` has comments and may or may not have parent ie any model can be a first model and any model can start a new branch of its own by starting from any parent

```
INSERT INTO BaseDomainTable ([BaseModelId],[Comments],[ParentModelId]) 
VALUES (1, 'Comments 1', NULL), (2, 'Comments 2', 1),
       (3, 'Comments for 3', 2), (4, 'Comments 4', 2)
```

After this insert, 1 is my base parent, 2 is derived from 1, 3 and 4 are derived from 2.

To get the data in a hierarchical format I have added a cte.

```
WITH ParentCTECheck (BaseModelId, Comments, ParentModelId) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Parent.BaseModelId, Parent.Comments, Parent.ParentModelId 
    FROM
        BaseDomainTable Parent
    WHERE 
        Parent.ParentModelId IS NULL 
        AND Parent.Comments IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        Derived.BaseModelId, Derived.Comments, Derived.ParentModelId  
    FROM
        BaseDomainTable Derived 
    JOIN
        ParentCTECheck ON ParentCTECheck.BaseModelId = Derived.ParentModelId
    WHERE 
        Derived.ParentModelId IS NOT NULL 
        AND Derived.Comments IS NOT NULL 
)
SELECT * 
FROM ParentCTECheck
```

AND I am getting this output:

```
BaseModelId    Comments      ParentModelId
------------------------------------------
1              Comments 1      NULL
2              Comments 2       1
3              Comments for 3   2
4              Comments 4       2
```

I want to change it such that if I pass in the BaseModelId as 4 the cte will traverse the loop for 4 and skip all the data related to 3 in this case and return data for 4,2,1. And when I pass 2 it should skip both 3 and 4 and get the CTE will traverse loop of 2 ie 2,1

Is there a way that this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to traverse the tree bottom up:

```
;WITH ParentCTECheck AS (
   -- Anchor query: get leaf node
   SELECT BaseModelId, Comments, ParentModelId
   FROM BaseDomainTable
   WHERE BaseModelId = 4 -- <-- Id of leaf node

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive query: go up the tree and get next level nodes.
   -- Recursion terminates as soon as the parent node is met.
   SELECT bt.BaseModelId, bt.Comments, bt.ParentModelId
   FROM BaseDomainTable AS bt
   JOIN ParentCTECheck AS ct ON bt.BaseModelId = ct.ParentModelId
)   
SELECT *
FROM ParentCTECheck
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7850a4/1)

Comment: The reverse logic did work the way I was expecting. Thanks

Comment: @JohnyL Why is this so?